How to add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath for VSCode
IntelliJ has a feature in the Run/Debug Configurations tab where the user is able to configure the option Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath under the Application configuration, by adding a run option to do so.
Under VSCode, I currently have installed the Java plugins alongside the extension pack by vscjava, and see the following options:

Maven
Outline
Timeline
Projects
Run Configuration
Java Projects

I thought that a similar option would be present under Run Configuration, but it's not very clear how to configure that part.
How can I get the the add dependency function functionality on VSCode?

Is there a specific reason you need to change that? I think the JDT-LS-based extension (which you are using) should do that automatically when running a Java application...

I don't think he needs it for running - Maven could take care. For intellisense VSCode needs more information, but now I am guessing.

I am developing an application on Apache Flink, just using it from vscode does not run the word count example, and most posts I've seen are people commenting to enable the add dependencies with provided scope in IntelliJ but that is not the ide I want to use.

Maven should enable that by default...Check if there is any unexpected added in the pom and remove them.

There shouldn't be any, I can execute the main class by doing mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.path.to.main.clazz" -Dexec.classpathScope="compile" on the command line

Maybe you could try using VSCode task if you can make this a command line as there is no native support for adding dependency for provided scope as Intellij IDEA.
